# Remove nested attributes from dynamoDB Items - nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a single item in dynamodb

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "201907240815": {
        "userid1": {
            "name": "Hello",
            "email": "test@example.com"
        },
        "userid2": {
            "name": "World",
            "email": "world@example.com"
        }
    }
}
```

I need to remove the nested attribute. ex:`201907240815.userid1`.

I had to try below code but it not worked

```
const param = {
    TableName:'userinfo',
    Key:{id:'123'},
    UpdateExpression:'remove 201907240815.userid1',
    ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW'
}
try{
const response = await dynamoDB.update(param).promise();
return response;
}catch(e){
return e;
}
```

It could not be remove the attribute. I got this issue.

```
ValidationException: Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: "201907240815", near: "remove 201907240815."
```

Comment: How do you check if the attribute get removed?

Comment: Sory, ReturnValue not include in Param.

Answer (score 0):

I think that 'remove' should be capitalized: 'REMOVE'